# Unable to run migration via artisan command

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, laravel-migrations

I have a Laravel 7 project and pushed it to a live server for production but I can't run migration successfully.  I always get an error 'access denied' error.

I can confirm that the command sees the .env file and the connection details are all correct. When I ssh into the server and run `mysql` command using same parameters saved in the .env file, connection is successful.  Adding the details into workbench and SequelPro also works so I am not sure why `php artisan migrate` doesn't work

Comment: did you run php artisan config:clear?

Comment: Yes I did run config:clear but same error

Comment: Ok run `php artisan tinker` and then do a `env('DB_USERNAME')` and so on to see what does the system prints

Comment: ok, so this is very useful and should be an answer.  Why does laravel trim passwords in DB_PASSWORD? or is it dotenv? there seems to be a limit?

Comment: Ok I shall post that as an answer. And yes `env` considers that as a string. Internally it uses `dotenv`.

Comment: Your welcome. Please have a look at the answer. If it helps please mark it as accepted and upvote. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the following command:

```
php artisan tinker
```

> Tinker is Laravel's own repl.

It will prompt you to enter the commands. Here you can check and print the value of the environment variables by entering string inside `env` method.

```
>>> env('DB_DATABASE')
```

and so on for the other **DB parameters**.

Hope this helps.

For more help you can check out the official Github repository of **tinker**:
https://github.com/laravel/tinker